# jQuery insert row with row number in names

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a markup like this

```
<table id="document-data">
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>Select Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="new-document-meta">
        <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="title"></td>
        <td>
            <select name="select-test[0]">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<a href="#" id="add-row">Add row</a>
```

Now here you can see I have the add-row. So when I will click on add-row it will just add another row to the table. Also with another added row the name field will add the row name like this
for 2nd row the name tag for title will become title_2 like so on.
So for that I made my js like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('a#add-row').click(function() {
            var Rows = $('table#document-data tr').length;
            var ParentClone = $('table#document-data tr.new-document-meta').last();
            var ParentHtml = $('table#document-data tr').last();
            ParentClone.clone().insertAfter(ParentHtml).find("select").each(function() {
                var $item=$(this);
                $item.prop("name","select-test["+Rows+"]");
            });
            $(ParentClone).find('input').each(function() {
                $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('name') + Rows);
            });
        });
    });
```

Here it is working fine for select tag but its not working for inputs tag. So can someone help me here?

Comment: It is working already, but sequence of tr is not proper. see this http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/r4gcaktk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ParentClone.find('input').each(function() {
                $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('name') + Rows);
            });
```

No need to have $ around it.

Answer (score 0):

there is some silly mistake as its not jquery selector so no need to write $

```
ParentClone.find('input').each(function() {
                $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('name') + Rows);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

**ParentClone** is already jquery object which you have defined above in code:

```
var ParentClone = $('table#document-data tr.new-document-meta').last();
```

it is not selector so you don't need to do `$(ParentClone)` as it is already jquery object just use it `ParentClone.find(....)`

```
ParentClone.find('input').each(function() {
```

Comment: Yes but can you see that when a new row is adding its name is coming like this 1, 12, 123 and so on. I am asking about that

Answer (score 0):

For the incremental name value, you need to cast the number of rows as string when you define it, then it will concatenate as desired when defining the name attribute. Replace your Rows defintion with this:

```
var Rows = String($('table#document-data tr').length);
```