# jQuery add row number in name tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have markup like this

```
<table id="document-data">
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>Select Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="new-document-meta">
        <td><input type="text" name="name[][0]"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="title[][0]"></td>
        <td>
            <select name="select-test[][0]">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<a href="#" id="add-row">Add row</a>
```

Here you can see when I will click on Add row then it will add another row with the number of row in the name. Here its working fine with the select tag but with the input name tags its not working properly. My js is like this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '#add-row', function(e) {
        var ParentClone = $('table#document-data tr.new-document-meta').last();
        var Rows = $('table#document-data tr').length-1;
        console.log(Rows);
        var ParentHtml = $('table#document-data tr').last();
        ParentClone.clone().insertAfter(ParentHtml).find("select").each(function() {
            var $item=$(this);
            $item.prop("name","select-test[]["+ Rows+"]");
        });
        ParentClone.find('input').each(function() {
                        $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('name') + []["+Rows+"]);
        });            

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `.prop()` is typically reserved for boolean attributes — to modify the value of the `name` attribute, you should use `.attr()` instead.

Comment: Please don't create several copies of the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25743748/jquery-insert-row-with-row-number-in-names) - you can update an existing one.

Comment: @Terry `.prop` is not limited to boolean attributes. Tag properties allow you to store virtually anything on the element, as opposed to attributes, which are always interpreted as strings.

Comment: @Terry, that's not true at all. `.prop` is meant for getting/setting object properties, plain and simple. Consider `typeof $("p").prop("style") // CssStyleDeclaration` or `typeof $("form").prop("elements"); // object`

Answer (score 0):

You have your quotes in the wrong places for the input tags:

```
ParentClone.find('input').each(function() {
    var currentName = $(this).attr("name");
    currentName = currentName.replace(/.+\[\]\[(\d+)\]/g, "");
    $(this).attr('name', currentName + "[]["+Rows+"]");
});
```

Or using regex replace:

```
ParentClone.find('input').each(function() {
    var currentName = $(this).attr("name");
    currentName = currentName.replace(/(.+\[\]\[)\d+(\])/g, "$1" + Rows + "$2");
    $(this).attr('name', currentName);
});
```

Comment: can you check the code? Its showing name like `name[][0][][1]`

Comment: Sorry. Didn't realize you were trying to 'reuse' the name. You'll have to filter out the original brackets and re-append them. You could also do a regex replace to get it all in one go.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the meta character with two slashes in jquery like below:

```
.prop("name","select-test\\[\\]\\["+ Rows+"\\]");
```